# Antlr: how to match everything between the other recognized tokens?

Tags: antlr, antlr4, lexical-analysis

How do I match all of the leftover text between the other tokens in my lexer?

Here's my code:

```
grammar UserQuery;

expr:  expr AND expr
    | expr OR expr
    | NOT expr
    | TEXT+
    | '(' expr ')'
    ;

OR  :    'OR';
AND :    'AND';
NOT :    'NOT';
LPAREN : '(';
RPAREN : ')';

TEXT: .+?;
```

When I run the lexer on "xx AND yy", I get these tokens:

```
x type:TEXT
x type:TEXT
  type:TEXT
AND type:'AND'
  type:TEXT
y type:TEXT
y type:TEXT
```

This sort-of works, except that I don't want each character to be a token. I'd like to consolidate all of the leftover text into a single TEXT token.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible without a delimiter, otherwise the greedy (?) lexer token will match **all** your input, including your explicit tokens, on the principle that longest match wins with lexer tokens.

Now, if you can accept that a delimiter is needed to delineate the text, and the addition of a simple whitespace rule to handle the spaces in between, then you get something like this:

```
[@0,0:14=''longest token'',<TEXT>,1:0]
[@1,16:18='AND',<'AND'>,1:16]
[@2,20:23=''yy'',<TEXT>,1:20]
[@3,24:23='<EOF>',<EOF>,1:24]
```

From this grammar:

```
grammar UserQuery;

expr:  expr AND expr
    | expr OR expr
    | NOT expr
    | TEXT
    | '(' expr ')'
    ;

OR  :    'OR';
AND :    'AND';
NOT :    'NOT';
LPAREN : '(';
RPAREN : ')';

TEXT : '\'' .*? '\'';
WS: [ \t\r\n] -> skip;
```

Using this input:

```
'longest token' AND 'yy'
```

It's very similar to the way comments and strings are often handled in programming languages, where there's a starting and ending delimiter and everything in between is tokenized as one big token.  Often with comments we'd discard them, but here we keep them as we would a string.  Hope this helps.

Comment: It does help, thank you. It would force me to change my query language, though. Trying not to do that.